# Linking to a custom google map

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm trying to add a Map element to an app that I'm developing. I know how to add a google map, and add overlays through the many tutorials there are online. What I want to do however is link to a google map that I've already created online in google maps "My Places" (this has around 100 place markers that regularly change). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow... Have you tried to write any code ? could you put it here too ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow... Have you tried to write any code ? could you put it here too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to just pass the information over to google maps app and let them help by creating a button that simply launches google maps with the link to the specific map as a DataUri. Heres the code below for my solution, if anyone else with a similar need stumbles across this.

```
Button map = (Button)findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {
            String uri = String.format("https://maps.google.co.uk/....."); // the link copied and pasted from my maps in google 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simply add a webview and load your Google Map inside, if it's a web version.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking of doing that, but would this allow full interaction with the map?